# Search starts when Edittext has at least 3 letters

Tags: android, search, android-edittext

I am working in an Android studio project. Here I want to implement one searching system. I have an `edittext` and an `imagebutton`. When user writers something in `edittext` and press `imagebutton`, system shows the relevant data from some database. This much I have covered.

Moreover, I want to implement a system where while user writes at least a specific length of letters (say 3) in `edittext`, the searching will start automatically. With more adding of letters the searching will be filtered accordingly. Is it possible to do this? Or something similar to this?

Comment: could you add relevant code?

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck? take a look for your question [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on searchview there is this syntax. just check the length of the text

```
    public void onQueryTextChange(String query) {
       if(query.length() >= 3) {
          searchStarts();
       }
    }
```

or if you dont use search view just use textwatcher

```
textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.length() > 3){
                    searchStarts();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add text watcher to your edit text. I will show you the solution with using debounce to avoid updating list all time user type a text.
So lets start with adding textWatcher to your edittext field:

```
searchField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //this one is for all letters, you can check the s length eg if(s.length() >= 3)
            searchSubject.onNext(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

This solution use rxjava if you do not want to do it just replace searchSubject with calling your search method.
So the fields:

```
private PublishSubject<String> searchSubject = PublishSubject.create();
private Subscription searchSubscription;
private String currentSearchPrefix = "";
```

And subscription (call this method onResume):

```
/**
 * Subscribe to searchSubject to update list of items depends on given prefix.
 * Debounce on changes 500 milliseconds
 */
private void subscribeSearch() {
    searchSubscription = searchSubject
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .onBackpressureLatest()
            .subscribe(result -> {
                currentSearchPrefix = result;
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(this::refreshList);
            });
}
```

My method refreshList just update list by filter it using currentSearchprefix by one of field. Remember to unsubscribe searchSubscription onPause().